# JSONIFY Filter Odd Behavior in Jekyll

Tags: json, jekyll, liquid

### Goal

Display JSON similar to this from links that have the same category minus the current page.

```
"relatedLink": [ "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html", "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html", "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html" ],
```

### Code

```
{% capture results %}[
{% for category in page.categories %}
{% for post in site.categories[category] %}
{% if post.url != page.url %} 
   {{ post.url | relative_url | prepend: site.url | replace:"&nbsp;", "," | jsonify  }}{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %}]{% else %}{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
    "relatedLink": {{ results }},
```

#### Results Error in JSON-LD

```json
"relatedLink": [ "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html" "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html" "https://example.com/category-slug/page-title.html" ],
```

`jsonify` did not comma separate the values in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is expected behavior. You're calling `jsonify` on `post.url`. `jsonify` converts Hashs or Arrays to JSON, not strings.

The best way to get what you want is probably this:

```html
{% capture results %}[
  {% for category in page.categories %}
    {% for post in site.categories[category] %}
      {% if post.url != page.url %} 
        "{{ post.url | relative_url | prepend: site.url }}"{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}]
{% endcapture %}

"relatedLink": {{ results }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I learned something new about `jsonify` that I did not know.

Comment: How can I also check for posts category in a collection?

Comment: Posts category? Do you mean you want to check which categories a post has? Or are you looking to loop posts in a specific category? Probably best to start a new question.

Comment: I have a collection that has cats. It's not being picked up. Thinking how to maybe do an OR?

Comment: I have a collection that has categories. The above answer does not cover them. I'm now,  looking for a way to check posts. If not a post check collection page for categories.